# Device Detection Mostly Without False Positive?

Tags: javascript, mobile, device, detection

So I am thinking of implementing some kind of device detection, but I would love it to be as on point as possible of course, with the least amount of false positives as possible.

What do you guys recommend for device detection? Server side I'm using ASP classic. Is parsing user agents good enough in this case?

My goal is to differentiate mobile and desktop devices, mostly without false positives.

Comment: _“So I am thinking of implementing some kind of device detection”_ – to achieve _what_, exactly?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: What's a "Bulletproof Device?"

Comment: My goal is to differentiate mobile and desktop devices, mostly without false positives.